# Пишу бот для Телеграм, при нажатии на start не отправляет приветствие

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

пишу бот для Телеграм на JS, почему он не отправляет приветствие при нажатии на start?

```
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf');

const bot = new Telegraf('Мой токен');

bot.start((ctx) =\> ctx.reply('Welcome'));
bot.launch();

// Enable graceful stop
process.once('SIGINT', () =\> bot.stop('SIGINT'));
process.once('SIGTERM', () =\> bot.stop('SIGTERM'));
```

Хотелось бы узнать в чём ошибка

Comment: `(ctx) =\> ctx.reply('Welcome')` убери лишний символ (везде) `(ctx) => ctx.reply('Welcome')`

Comment: Я взял твой код... Убрал лишние символы... Подставил свой токен... Запустил - все работает.

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо, не работало потому что некорректно библиотеки подгрузились, ну и лишние символы конечно же тоже